# How to replace string of a webpage using firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I want to create an addon whose xpi installation will enable to replace a string of a website with other string.

For example , replacing all "the"s in a webpage with "change".
Actually, wanted to create an addon for a site due to which some complex word occuring multiple times could changed to a simpler word with a toolbar button click or by selection of the word and changing the word via clicking an option in the context-menu

Thnaks advance. Will give some more info if required.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.

This is a simple thing to do, however it is very tricky to do it right. Right - means that it is done in a way that is safe from XSS attacks, and done very efficiently. It is common to see people not walking the tree, and doing all kinds of non-performant stuff.

What people do is copy paste this add-on and just modify the `replaceText` function -

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/361576/file/data/content-script.js

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. Will get back to you after trying it out.

Comment: Works Well..!! Thanks a ton for such a quick reply. And yes.. actually tendency of people would be to just modify the replace text.. lol..!!

Comment: one more thing.. can we add an hyperlink to the replaced text?

Comment: @Aksh1693 you absolutely can. You just have to do `createElement('a')` then `setAttribute` to inject it into that spot.

Comment: (say for eg:)

function replaceText(v){

    v = v.replace(/\bHate\b/g, "Love");

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', 'google.com');
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
}
I m using the above syntax.. but the problem is that I cant figure out how to extract the replaced text. I mean where to append the hyperlink so that the desired replace text could be hyperlinked.

Comment: sorry for the trouble...Thanks in advance

Comment: @Aksh1693 can you ask another question please. I'm not exactly sure off the top of my head how to do it. Hopefully someone else will chime in. If they don't I'll look it up and reply.

Comment: cool..no problemo.. lets c if someone else has the answer.. till the time  i`ll also dig up on this... n will post if i found something..